# Django ensure blank field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to be able to disable the ability to fill in a field, while having it still be created in the DB.

This column will be dependent on the rest of the rows in the table, and always will, so it is a necessary column, but the information cannot be given during creation. Here is what I have:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    some_field = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True)
    another_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.some_field:
            self.some_field = FooBar.objects.filter(another_field=self.another_field).count() + 1
            super(FooBar,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

this makes sense logically, you can create a `FooBar` instance and then once it is saved, if `some_field` is blank, it will assign it based on how many rows are in the table dependent on `another_field`. But here is the problem:

**What if, when creating the instance, a value was given for `some_field`? That is possible and would break everything...how can that be prevented?**

note: I apologize if there are any errors in the code, I have not run any of it, it is just pseudo code to display a level of dependency, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Set [`editable=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.editable) on the field. This will remove it from any ModelForms and from the admin. It won't prevent you from setting the value elsewhere in the code, though.

Comment: so then this is not what I am looking for. Thanks anyways

Comment: It's exactly what you're looking for, but you probably want override the save method as well to calculate what value would be assigned to the field

Comment: this is for an internal API, so these are not being created through forms or the admin, they are being created within scripts, which, as stated above, `editable=False` does not prevent.

Comment: If you don't need forms etc, maybe you can create an intermediate layer of abstraction, that is the only place that directly accesses the database layer. That way you can use this layer to dictate access rules and set the `some_field` values

Comment: and how would I go about that?

Comment: You could implement something like [the facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). It really depends on the user of the API...

Answer (score 0):

You can override your model's [validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) function to add custom code.

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    ...
    # You're trying to force a single field to be blank, so you need to
    # override clean_fields().
    # If several fields were required to validate, clean() would be more
    # appropriate
    def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
        super(models.Model, self).clean_fields(exclude)

        # Check if the field should be ignored (for consistency)
        if "your_field_that_should_be_blank" not in exclude:
            # Validate the data. I'm assuming the field holds strings
            if self.your_field_that_should_be_blank != "":
                # Raise a ValidationError if invalid
                raise ValidationError("That field should be blank")
```